# docker - sh: nodemon: not found

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am creating a docker container on my ec2 instance.

When I run `docker-compose up --build`, container `test-web` is not created successfully.
I tried to run `docker logs test-web` and see the logs, then I see below error

`sh: nodemon: not found`

I tried to add nodemon dependency on package.json and run `docker-compose up --build` again but still not working.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  test-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  test-web:
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
      #- DEBUG=*
      - PORT=3030
    build: .
    command: >
      ./wait-for-db-redis.sh test-db npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/server
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    depends_on:
      - test-db
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch src/",
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add `RUN npm install --global nodemon` in `Dockerfile` and it works now.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm install --global nodemon

WORKDIR /server

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```